# How to add peer via solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-invocation

we are clear that in geth console we can add another peer with addpeer command such as

```
admin.addPeer("enode://41bd7d2fe91b344f0ca4ac89c217d688ef90a3616927acec428adddbc69dd2ac5470a489fd2beb67719cbd481436b98284ef9eac50efa49f55fe33e804818520@10.0.50.91:30303")
```

so, my question is that how to add another peer in solidity contract?

Comment: You can't do it, the smart contract has no such ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peer is a property of an Ethereum node which is local to a computer, whereas a contract code can run on any node. There are no "peers" from the POV of a contract.